Does .NET have an official or standard class for arrays that use value equality rather than reference equality?
I keep running into cases where I need an array with value equality. An array of records that itself acts record-ishly. At the moment I'm working on an IIncrementalGenerator and want all the intermediate data to be properly memoized and cached. I've found numerous folk writing and suggesting basically the same "wrap an array, pass through all the functions, add overrides for Equals and == and != and GetHashCode" code. GitHub Copilot and ChatGPT are excited to write it for me. All with various array methods left out or fiddly little differences. I've also found documentation that declares vigorously that ImmutableArray<T> actually does this and yet when I just tried it, I definitely got only reference equality. I'm about to write my own Array_ValueEquality type (more likely copy-paste one) but it feels sort of icky.
Am I missing something?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.istructuralequatable?view=net-8.0

So if the AI tools are leaving some of the methods out, then implement those methods.  What's the problem?  Do you not know how to implement them?  If so, you'll need to explain what the problem is and why you're struggling with it.

LINQ operations. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/array-mapping-in-ef-core-8/

IStructuralEquatable is really slow because it boxes every value-type value encountered. If SequenceEquals (either from LINQ or from MemoryExtensions) can be used, that's a much better option. A hash code calculation will have to be implemented manually.

No, you are not missing anything. There is no such predefined type. ImmutableArray<T> deliberately does not use value equality according to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77183#issuecomment-1947713649 .
If you're writing a Roslyn incremental source generator, https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeShape.Roslyn (pointed to in another comment at the above issue) may be good.
Otherwise, the functionality may be too small to justify adding a NuGet package.
